# Help needed in solving a graph problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following problem which I cannot solve. I'm trying to improve my skills in discrete mathematics so any help will be appreciated. Here is the problem:

The graph $G(V,E)$ is 3-regular (exactly 3 edges come from each  vertex).  In $G$ there are no cycles with length 3 or 4. Prove that $G$ has at least 10 vertices. Is it possible $G$ to have exactly 10 vertices.

Comment: What is the exact difficulty you're having proving that? Have you made any headway?

Comment: @MikePierce biggest difficulty for me at least is to write the proof correctly.

Comment: Yeah, proof writing can be pretty tough. You should include your attempt at a proof when you post a question like this though, even if you don't think you're right or you're not happy with what you've got. Users of this site tend to be more welcoming to new users who "*show some effort at answering there own question.*"

Answer (score 4):

A vertex $v$ has three neighbors: $x$, $y$, and $z$. Each of these vertices has three neighbors: $x$ has $v$, $a$, and $b$; $y$ has $v$, $c$, and $d$; $z$ has $v$, $e$, and $f$.

If these vertices are all different, then you have ten vertices. Can any of them be the same? For example, can $x$ be the same vertex as $c$, or $a$ be the same vertex as $f$?

To answer the "is it possible" question, you could either take the vertex and the edges we've drawn so far and try to complete them, or think about well-known examples of graphs.

Comment: Expanding a little on Misha Lavrov's answer a little, you can argue by contradiction and extremality. Suppose for a contradiction such a graph $G$ with fewer than $10$ vertices exists. As $G$ is $3$-regular, $G$ has at most $8$ vertices. Now employ Misha Lavrov's approach to derive a contradiction.